# NPM /.config and /.npm doesn't exist. OS X won't allow me to create then. NPM won't download any package

Tags: node.js, macos, npm

So my problem is that i installed npm via nvm on Mac
When i installed it before with brew it had the same problem.
Every time i use npm for anything i get

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                   npm update check failed                   │
│             Try running with sudo or get access             │
│            to the local update config store via             │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/serwis24/.config │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

So i tried to use the command listed and it doesn't work. It says that this direcotry does not exist. So i tried to create it manually via mkdir command and it doesn't work even with sudo.

When i try to download any package it hangs on

```
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠇ rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session 5863b157ddbbc47
```

I tried upgrading / downgrading my node. It seems that the problem is something with permissions on my mac. Anyone maybe bumped into this problem before?

When i try to run sudo npm install --verbose i get

````
npm verb makeDirectory /Users/serwis24/.npm/_locks creation not in flight; initializing
⸨       ░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠏ postinstall: verb makeDirectory /Users/serwis24/.npm/_locks creation not```
````

Comment: Did you try to run NPM as super user? You can do that using `sudo` in front of your command. For example `sudo npm install package --save`

Comment: Yes i tried that and the effect is the same.